# get on which widget is tapped when adding widgets dynamically in a stack flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I am trying to add widgets dynamically in a stack like adding text fields on the screen. I am adding that. But on tapping a particular widget i want to rebuilt the that widget in stack. For that I want to get on which widget is tapped in stack. How can I do that.?**

```
List<Widget> customizedShirt = [];
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:Stack(
            children: customizedShirt,
          ),
       floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
        customizedShirt.add(Positioned(
          //New position for every new text in stack
          child:Text("New Text")));
          setstate((){});
        },
       
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is an example code now on tapping a particular text I want to rebuilt that text (Like changing its font, size etc) without changing the other texts in stack**